# What's the difference of using e.g. android:colorAccent and colorAccent attribute?

Tags: android, colors, themes

What's the difference if I use

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

or

```
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

?

The first one worked for me when I use it on my theme. It changed the default color of my progress bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`colorAccent` attribute (without android prefix) is provided by the support library, to bring compatibility with older APIs.
`android:colorAccent` atribute is supported only from API 21 and above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here's a follow up question. What should be the best practice if I want to maintain compatibility with older apps? Should I update the theme in both values\styles.xml and values-21\styles.xml? should I use the prefixed to the values-21\styles.xml and the non-prefixed on values\styles.xml?

Comment: Just only use `colorAccent` and remove your `values-v21/styles.xml` - AppCompatActivity already takes care of all that for you.